Chaning values to NA based on multiple columns
I have a data frame where I wish to change any values from a 0 to an NA but only of the values of paired columns are both 0. I have attached an example below of what I currently have and what I am trying to return. I think to do this its best to pair off the columns we want to check? then once we have identified the positions we want we can simply replace the 0s with NAs. I also thought there might be a way we couple use something like sapply but wasn't sure how we could pair  off columns 'a' and columns 'b'.
df
a1   a2    b1   b2
1     3    0    6
7     9    0    0    
5     5    4    6    
0     0    0    0     
0     0    6    0     

What I'm trying to achieve;
newdf
a1   a2    b1   b2
1     3    0    6
7     9    NA    NA    
5     5    4    6    
NA    NA   NA   NA     
NA    NA   6    0  


How about this:
unname(split.default(quux, sub("\\d", "", names(quux)))) |>
  lapply(function(z) { z[rowSums(z > 0) == 0,] <- NA; z; }) |>
  do.call(cbind, args = _)
#   a1 a2 b1 b2
# 1  1  3  0  6
# 2  7  9 NA NA
# 3  5  5  4  6
# 4 NA NA NA NA
# 5 NA NA  6  0


Data
quux <- structure(list(a1 = c(1L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 0L), a2 = c(3L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 0L), b1 = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 6L), b2 = c(6L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))


Perfect, thanks. Can you just remind me what the "\d" looks for in the sub please?

It's "regex" for "any number digit" (0-9). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 for a large list of regex stuff. There are other ways that could have been done with this sample data, such as split.default(quux, substring(names(quux), 1, 1)), but I thought that your real data might have more than single-letter column groups. The intent of the sub(.) or substring(.) is that is returns the same thing for similar columns: for the first two, it returns "a", and for the last two columns it returns "b". They do not need to be in consecutive order for the grouping to work.
